# Cloud-build Trigger

Tags: google-cloud-build

***1.I want to build trigger on Cloud build for only specific branches***

***2.It should work with both branches as well as tags in same trigger***

Any solution/suggestion

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Cloud build github app in order to set the triggers as mentioned on [this document](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/create-github-app-triggers). They do support both builds triggered with branches or tags, however you would not be able to trigger them with both.

You would need to create a separate trigger for the branch and for the tag, and also keep in mind that this feature is in beta, so I wouldn't recommend you using this in any production environment.

Hope you find this useful.